# Simulating longer mouse button press in python

Tags: python, time, automation, mouse

Okay, so I want to make mouse macro in Python 3.8 that will automatically press and release mouse buttons (combination for fishing game, so that I don't have to manually repeat clicking mouse buttons). I have read descriptions for both mouse module and PyAutoGUI module, and from what I can see, PyAutoGUI seems more powerful, but I don't know how to set time how long mouse button will be pressed in either of those. From what I can see they have "click" function, but I want to set how long the mouse button will be pressed. Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here there is the parameters for pyautogui.click()

```
x=None, y=None, clicks=1, interval=0.0, button=PRIMARY, duration=0.0, tween=linear, logScreenshot=None, _pause=True
```

as you can see you can modify the duration by saying

```
pyautogui.click(your_x, your_y, duration=5.0)
```

i have put five but you can put any float value

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot, I got 2 questions. First where did you find those parameters for that function because I can't find them online. Second is harder one, how could I set up a hotkey that would start that "macro" and also how to make it stop (I don't know how many times it will have to repeat so I would probably put those mouse movements in endless loop, but then I need a way to stop it).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but for anyone coming across this wildly incorrect answer in the future: the duration parameter for the click function in pyautogui affects how long it takes the mouse to move from its current position to the click location. It does not affect how long the click lasts (i.e., how long the button is pressed).

The only way I have found to manipulate the length of the click is to use the individual mouseDown and mouseUp functions, with a sleep function between them. This is less than ideal, because even without the sleep function, the mouseDown and mouseUp functions are so slow that your minimum click time is over one second long. Still, this works:

```
pyautogui.moveto(x, y)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
time.sleep(N)
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

...where x and y are the mouse coordinates to click on, and N is the number of seconds you want to wait during the click.